# Java Regex: Matching the beginning of a line

Tags: java, regex

I am reading through a number of text files that are a dump of e-mail messages.  I am trying to check if the line I am reading starts with "Cc:".  For example I would want to match the following example line "Cc:\temail1@example.com; email2@exmaple.com".

The code that I am using looks like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^Cc\\:");
line = reader.readLine();

if (pattern.matcher(line).matches()) {
   System.out.println(line);
}
```

Any idea why this is not matching?

Comment: The regex `^Cc\\:` does not match your input "Cc:", it's as simple as that. Remove the backslashes.

Comment: @Jongware but the backslashes should not make a difference. `"\\:"` makes the regex `\:` which is a literal `:` (colons don't need to be escaped, but doing so doesn't cause a problem). To put a literal backslash in a regex, you must code `"\\\\"`

Comment: @Bohemian: But, unless Java's GREP is *real* strict, then the OP's regex should have worked, right? Escaping a character that doesn't *need* it is usually okay. (For a reasonable definition of "usually"--in my native environments it is, anyway.)

Comment: -- For the record, I *do* agree on double-double backslashes in languages that already treat the backslash as 'special' inside strings.

Comment: @Jongware unless there is a type-o in the example line, then the position of the semicolon in the pattern is wrong, and the "GREP" shouldnt match :)

Comment: @Jongware I figured it out... See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your regex per se (although you have unnecessarily escaped the colon, but bit will still work), but the reason it's not working is that in java (unlike most other popular languages) `matches()` must match the *whole* string. Change your regex to `"Cc:.*"`. Note how in java you don't need the ^ or $ because they are implied due to having to match the whole string.

However, for a simpler case-insensitive check using regex:

```
if (line.matches("(?i)cc:.*")) // note the .*
```

Or without regex:

```
if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("cc:"))
```